# Bitbucket pipelines could not find Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, bitbucket, gradlew, bitbucket-pipelines

I created a project with Java 11 and Gradle 6.2. I configured Bitbucket pipelines and pushed changes, but Bitbucket could not find Gradle to run its commands.
I used this pipeline configuration yml:

```sh
image: openjdk:11

pipelines:
  default: #this runs for any unspecified branches
    - step:
        name: Install dependencies
        caches:
          - gradle
        script:
          - echo 'Put any bash command here'
          - java -version
    - step:
        name: Run tests
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew test
    - step:
        name: Build artifacts
        script:
          - bash ./gradlew clean build
        artifacts:
          - build/**

  pull-requests:
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          name: Install dependencies
          caches:
            - gradle
          script:
            - echo 'Put any bash command here'
            - java -version
      - step:
          name: Run tests
          script:
            - bash ./gradlew test
      - step:
          name: Build artifacts
          script:
            - bash ./gradlew clean build
          artifacts:
            - build/**

  branches:
    master: #this runs only 'master' branch
      - step:
          name: Install dependencies
          caches:
            - gradle
          script:
            - echo 'Put any bash command here'
            - java -version
      - step:
          name: Run tests
          script:
            - bash ./gradlew test
      - step:
          name: Build artifacts
          script:
            - bash ./gradlew clean build
          artifacts:
            - build/**

      - step:
          name: Deploy artifacts to the server
          deployment: production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.3
              variables:
                USER: $SERVER_USER
                SERVER: $SERVER_IP
                VERSION: $BUILD_VERSION
                REMOTE_PATH: '/var/autotrack'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'build/libs/autotrack-$VERSION.jar'
```

But I got the following error:

> **`bash ./gradlew test`**
>    **`bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory`**

[image: Bitbucket Pipelines - CI build error]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openjdk:11` image does not contain Gradle. That's why we need to use another image that contains Java and Gradle in one place. For example, this `gradle:6.3.0-jdk11` image can be used.

```
image: gradle:6.3.0-jdk11

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Test and Build
        script:
          - gradle clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to run the build with this modified step, please?

```
- step:
    name: Run tests
    script:
      - bash ls -lart
      - bash ./gradlew test
```

I hope that this will clarify the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, It did not help. I think Bitbucket does not have Gradle by default.

Comment: I found the issue, Issue was with images. There are should be 2 images, Gradle and Java. I replaced the image with new `image: gradle:6.3.0-jdk11
` and this worked. But another issue I faced. The Issue with Testcontainers. Inside the Bitbucket, How can I use Tescontainers

Comment: I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138898/testcontainer-issue-with-bitbucket-pipelines