# Testcontainer issue with Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: java, docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

I configured bitbucket-pipelines.yml and used `image: gradle:6.3.0-jdk11`. My project built on Java11 and Gradle 6.3. Everything was Ok till starting test cases. Because I used Testontainers to test the application. Bitbucket could not start up the Testcontainer.
The error is: 
`org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed`

How can be fixed the issue?

Comment: Don't post images of text. Replace it with the actual text please.

Comment: Your Question is not clear, If you want to put it as an article then please specify the Actual problem with Exceptions, so that help seeker can relate thier problems with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If used Testcontainers inside the Bitbucket pipelines, There might be some issues. For instance, some issues like mentioned above. This issue can be fixed putting by following commands into `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`
Here the basic command is an environment variable.

`TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true`.
The full pipeline might be like this:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
          - mvn clean install
        services:
          - docker
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```

Comment: Not the Question was clear, neither posted Answer is!

Comment: bitbucket does not allow privileged container like RYUK to run for security reason. Adding "export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true" solves this problem.